# Repeated Heading Selectors

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors, csslint

With the recent launch of http://csslint.net, I'm questioning some ways I've constructed my stylesheets in the past. The following method is one that I've used recently:

```
/* Fonts */    
h1 { font-size:20px }
p  { font-size:12px }

/* Colors */
h1 { color:green }
p  { color:grey;
     background-color:white }

/* Margins */
h1 { margin:0 }
p  { margin:0 0 5px }
```

The problem, according to the linter, is that I'm re-declaring heading selectors over and over again. The reason of course is to keep logical separation between types of rules. If I wish to change colors, I would visit the colors region. If I wish to change dimensions, I would visit the dimensional areas.

Is CSSLint worried that I may be in danger of overwriting styles, thus wasting chars, or are there performance issue related to how many blocks contribute to the overall presentation of heading elements?

Is this a bad practice, or merely a false-alarm?

Comment: +1 just for trying out csslint so quickly!

Comment: Not everyone agrees with CSS Lint:  http://mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/1054/

Comment: @thirtydot I'm aware of those perspectives, and I agree with them on some parts. That being said, I do still find value in using a Lint for CSS as it will catch some mistakes. When it comes to items like this one, I'll simply go with my personal judgment and abandon the rule of CSSLint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles get computed for all `h1`s and all `p`s either way. The overhead of selector matching is little compared to the equally-negligible performance "impact" of actually computing and rendering the styles.

I'm guessing what you think CSS Lint is worried about is the case. In fact, I kinda like how you organize your styles myself, and don't see any other problems than overwriting declarations by accident.

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation -

> Heading elements should have a consistent appearance across a site.

I think it is more to do with usability/consistency rather than performance. A heading of size 20px on one page and 14px on another just looks unprofessional.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not breaking this rule. I'm declaring aspects of the presentation in multiple blocks. The size is set once, globally, and the margins would be set once, globally. The thing is that both rules are present in two different blocks which raises warning flags about duplicate selectors.